# link doesn't work in the my slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slideshow

When I added links to the following slides, the only link that I am able to link to is the last slide no matter what I put. Is there any way I can use this slide code and also have the link works properly the same time?

html

```
<ul class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/slider1.png" style="background-color:red;"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/slider2.png" style="background-color:white;"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/slider3.png"  style="background-color:yellow;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="http://codepen.io/"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/slider4.png"   style="background-color:blue;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="nav-dots">
  <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot"></label>
  <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot"></label>
  <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot"></label>
  <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot"></label>
</li>
```

css

```
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 241px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 980px;
    height: 241px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 50pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 225px;
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s slide;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

js

```
setInterval(function(){
$(".next:visible").click();}, 5000);
```

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONqpKa)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand as I am getting different links for all the slides.

Comment: @Developer107 When I click any slide, it always leads to codepen.io which is the link of the last slide. I need each slide to links to different site. Would you be able to figure out how?

Answer (score 0):

There was a css issue regarding `z-index`. I have given a z-index value of 10 to the active slide corresponding to `checked` radio button.

```
input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 10;
   transition: opacity 1s slide;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
   display: block;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

But you won't be able to access those sites in codepen, except codepen itself, in the same tab. Instead just **open in new tab** and see.

Refer this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rg51b4s0/1/) where you won't be able to open any of the 4 sites, unless you don't open them in new tab.